# Multiple notifications with actions

Tags: android, notifications

My app issues multiple notifications that all may have Jelly Bean style actions [1].

It seems that when I issue multiple notifications, only the last one will have action buttons and I cannot figure out why.

I use a custom intent action for the pendingIntents of every notification and action.

Does anybody know how to create two notifications at the same time that both have action buttons visible?

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#addAction(int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 3):

Per the [Notification's documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#BigNotify),

> A notification's big view appears only when the notification is expanded, which happens when the notification is at the top of the notification drawer, or when the user expands the notification with a gesture

If you have multiple notifications, be sure to expand the lower ones using one of the gestures as explained on the [design page for notifications](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) - I expect that they do have the action controls but are just not expanded.

Comment: You are perfectly right. All action buttons are there but only the top ones are displayed. When you long-press the notification, you are able to expland the notification.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. Is there a reason you need more than one notification with an action button? Although action buttons are a nice way of connecting "instantly" with an app, they're primarily for use with something that's running even though you want the UI to be minimal. The best example of this is a media player: you don't want to shut it down, but you don't want to force users to go to the app to control play/pause.

Comment: The notifications are basically alerts of alarms that users registered before. The alarms are independent can individually be dismissed. That's why I want dismiss buttons for each notification entry.